# Create an embeddable "widget" from the JS script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, embed

I would like to be able to embed the content that gets created via this snippet anywhere I like, using one line of code - same way that you get any kind of snippet somewhere, so that it renders an `iframe` or similar in return. I am not sure where to start with that, and if this what I already have is usable/ready to "convert" to an embeddable snippet. I went through a few tutorials but it was quite confusing since it was using some backend stuff I don't really understand...

Obviously, it should be hosted somewhere, but the part where I need to "call" the snippet is not really clear to me. Now, it just appears everywhere on my website since it's just a normal JS file which gets included, same as all other files.

It would be great if I could just pack it somehow and call it like this let's say:

```
<script src="link-to-my-snippet.js"></script>
```

If someone could direct me a bit that would be great.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 40
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    age: 50
  }
];

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  function Item(configurationObject) {
    apiCall(data);
  }

  function apiCall(data) {
    // Do some API call and get back the data
    // With the Unique ID that wass passed in via the 
    // configuration Object
    // "data" is faked just for the demonstration
    createHTML(data);
  }

  function createHTML(data) {
    const mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
    let html = '';

    data.forEach((user) => {
      html += `
          <div class="test">
              <p>${user.name}</p>
              <p>${user.age}</p>
          </div>
        `;
    });

    mainDiv.innerHTML = html;

    createStylesheet();
  }

  function createStylesheet() {
    const style = document.createElement("style");
    style.innerHTML = `
        .test {
                background-color: lightgreen;
            color: white;
        }
    `;

    document.head.appendChild(style);
  }

  let configurationObject = {
    uniqueID: 1234
  }

  let initialize = new Item(configurationObject);
});
```

Comment: `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"` should call the snippet?

Comment: @evolutionxbox huh, not sure if that's right, yeah. It should be called with a script tag... is this redundant in that case?

Comment: What are the requirements for "anywhere I like"? Do you mean some pages should show it and others should not show the widget? In that case: what does your setup look like? In case you have a very basic setup with html files, it's very easy. In the file "index.html" you include the script element, in the html file "my-products.html" you do not add the script element. Problem solved. So, to be able to answer your question, it is vital to know what the backend looks like.

Comment: I understand, however I'm looking to make something like YT embed widget, or similar - so something that does not 'need' the backend, but creates the elements and styles on its own, and can be just inserted via script element... not sure if that's possible then after I read these comments... I'll rethink it a bit, thanks for the input

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Using modern javascript - ES6, Webpack, SCSS, and then bundle all in a single file using NPM
   Follow: https://blog.jenyay.com/building-javascript-widget/
2. Pure JavaScript - Custom Created.

You can create a self-executable anonymous function like this and write your complete widget code - including your HTML, CSS, etc inside this. It will be executed once your page is loaded with this script.

```
(function() {
    // The following code will be enclosed within an anonymous function
    var foo = "Hello World!";
    document.write("<p>Inside our anonymous function foo means '" + foo + '".</p>');
})(); // We call our anonymous function immediately
```

For the second type solution you can also follow following article:
https://gomakethings.com/the-anatomy-of-a-vanilla-javascript-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have some local static HTML/CSS page.

First off, you don't need to render the generated HTML by the javascript in an iframe, almost any element will do. The purpose of JS is to create, manipulate and read DOM-elements, so don't feel limited.

Secondly, some of that code is useless for your purpose, unless you plan on doing stuff with an API (which I assume not), and have an actual need for a unique ID. In that code, that unique Id isn't unique anyway and isn't used for anything.

There is so many ways to implement this script on any page of your choice, but here's one:

You have a HTML-file, in that one, put:

```
<div id="users-list"></div>
```

wherever you want the list to appear.

Create a file called whatever you want, but for example *users-list.js*. Check the demo in my answer for the JS code to put in that file.

In any HTML file where you have added an element with the ID of 'users-list', simply also add the script in that same HTML file. Preferably before the  ending tag.

```
<script src="/path/to/users-list.js"></script>
```

Of course, you make this in so many ways, and expand on it infinitely. For example, something like this could be cool to have:

```
<div id="some-div-id"></div>

...

<script src="/path/users-list.js">
  getUsers({
    element: 'some-div-id'
    theme: 'dark',
    layout: 'boxes' // or 'rows'
  }); 
</script>
```

Then you could invoke the script on different pages with different generated HTML, but of course, that would require some modification of your JS code, to actually print out different css content, and getting the right element to place the data in.

In any case, it wouldn't be hard to do.

But back on topic, working demo:

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 40
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    age: 50
  }
];

const styles = `
    .user {
        background-color: lightgreen;
        color: white;
    }

    .age { font-weight: bold; }
`;

function setStyles() {
    const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    
    styleElement.innerHTML = styles;

    document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
}

function setUsers(users) {
    let element = document.getElementById('users-list')

    let usersHtml = '';

    users.forEach(user => {
        usersHtml += `
            <div class="user">
                <p class="name">${user.name}</p>
                <p class="age">${user.age}</p>
            </div>
        `;
    })

    if (element) element.innerHTML = usersHtml;
}



window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    setUsers(users);
    setStyles(styles); 
});
```

```html
<div id="users-list"></div>
```

**Here is an example of a self invoking recursive IIFE checking for the document readyState, better than the accepted answers solution**

```
const myPlugin = () => {
  // stuff
}

/** 
 *  Checks the document readyState until it's ready
 */
(ready = (delay) => {
  // this is always 'complete' if everything on the page is loaded,
  // if you want to check for a state when all html/js is loaded but not all assets, check for 'interactive'
  if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
    myPlugin() // your stuff being invoked when doc is ready
  } else {
    console.log('Retrying!')
    setTimeout(() => { ready(delay) }, delay)
  }
})(50)
```

Comment: No static HTML, everything needs to be generated via JS, and inserted in a way that Youtube gives you the embed code... Please check the comment above for more info, thank you

Comment: Ah, I see. As your comment reads: "not sure if that's possible then after I read these comments...", well, it is indeed possible to do what you want. 

Using an IIFE as Lovlesh is one suggested is just one way to run a function on a page when you desire it to be run. But what is worth noting is that calling an IIFE like that, or including a script that contains a function, and executing that function, is exactly the same thing, with different syntactic appearance.

Comment: You can most definitely generate all CSS and elements on the spot with javascript, at any point in the website/webapp lifecycle with just vanilla or with whatever tools you want. That's exactly how all modern web apps using React/Angular etc all work.

It's kinda what I meant with this: "Of course, you make this in so many ways, and expand on it infinitely".

Also, if you put all your code inside Lovleshs IIFE you would probably get errors since he isn't checking for DOMContentLoaded or any similar event, indicating the document is ready. There are numerous ways to do that as well.

Comment: Most JS "plugins" require the user to add some DOM-element to their site to wrap that the script will hook into. More often than not, this element is provided by something similar as I wrote, as a config object containing an element property or something.
So you often just include a script tag, and invoke the function from the script in your code. Or that script could be self-invoking as well, which is one way to make it. Then you wouldn't need to initialize it in your code, just include the script. However, that leaves less control since that script knows nothing of your DOM.

Comment: Thanks, very informative. So, if I had the element inside my HTML, the best way to run the script would be to first listen to DOMContentLoaded as I understood, to make sure the element is there. But again, we could create everything via JS, and invoke it via IIFE...

Comment: Hm, well, that is true, that you wouldn't need to check for a ready document if you are making all the elements on the fly. I guess I wrote a little too fast ;) so it would be more of help if you were depending on something being in the DOM, in the script.